# How to implement "IN" clause with Dapper Extensions Predicate?

Tags: c#, dapper, dapper-extensions

I want to replace this query using Dapper Extensions Predicate?

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE id IN (commaSeparatedListOfIDs)
```

The `commaSeparatedListOfIDs` is an `IEnumerable` of `Integer`.

What I have tried so far:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    var predicate = Predicates.Field<SomeTable>(f => f.Id, Operator.???, commaSeparatedListOfIDs);
    IEnumerable<SomeTable> list = cn.GetList<SomeTable>(predicate);
    cn.Close();
}
```

I need an operator `Operator.In`, but it does not exists in Dapper Extensions.

How should I implement "IN" clause with Dapper Extensions Predicate system?

Comment: I see. I don't think it is supported. File an issue https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions or, as I would recommend, use a better tool. Dapper Extensions is awkward at best.

Comment: @mr5 the operators available are like, equal, greater than, greater or equal, less than, less or equal. I do not know which use for accomplish the in clause.

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 1:**

Using `PredicateGroup` with `GroupOperator.Or` is one solution.

```
var predicateGroup = new PredicateGroup { Operator = GroupOperator.Or, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>() };
foreach(int thisID in commaSeparatedListOfIDs)
{
    var predicate = Predicates.Field<SomeTable>(f => f.Id, Operator.Eq, thisID);
    predicateGroup.Predicates.Add(predicate);
}
IEnumerable<SomeTable> list = cn.GetList<SomeTable>(predicateGroup);
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/issues/109) and [this](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates#multiple-compound-predicates-predicate-group) link.

**Solution 2:**

As you mentioned in your answer and [this](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/issues/164) link, using FieldPredicate (`Predicates.Field`) with `Operator.Eq`, and passing `IEnumerable` parameter should do the same.

```
var predicate = Predicates.Field<SomeTable>(f => f.Id, Operator.Eq, commaSeparatedListOfIDs);
```

Here `Eq` should be internally translated to **IN** clause as per [this](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/blob/dd82ecc6f710bca6d5e5645cbff8da97e411257f/DapperExtensions/Predicates.cs#L203) source code of Dapper Extensions on GitHub.

```
if(Value is IEnumerable && !(Value is string))
{
    if(Operator != Operator.Eq)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Operator must be set to Eq for Enumerable types");
    }

    List<string> @params = new List<string>();
    foreach(var value in (IEnumerable)Value)
    {
        string valueParameterName = parameters.SetParameterName(this.PropertyName, value, sqlGenerator.Configuration.Dialect.ParameterPrefix);
        @params.Add(valueParameterName);
    }

    string paramStrings = @params.Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, s) => sb.Append((sb.Length != 0 ? ", " : string.Empty) + s), sb => sb.ToString());
    return string.Format("({0} {1}IN ({2}))", columnName, Not ? "NOT " : string.Empty, paramStrings);
}
```

---

To turn the `IN` clause as mentioned above to `NOT IN` clause, use the last `bool not` parameter. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831728/5779732) answer for more details.
Sample code is as below:

```
var predicate = Predicates.Field<Customer>(f => f.CustomerID, Operator.Eq, commaSeparatedListOfIDs, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this link [Github Issue](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/issues/164)

> if you use a FieldPredicate, set to Equal and pass in an array it will translate to IN.

So, the correct way would be this.

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    var predicate = Predicates.Field<SomeTable>(f => f.Id, Operator.In, commaSeparatedListOfIDs);
    IEnumerable<SomeTable> list = cn.GetList<SomeTable>(predicate);
    cn.Close();
}
```