# How to implement “NOT IN” clause with Dapper Extensions Predicate?

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions

I found how to implement `IN` clause using Dapper Extensions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777139/how-to-implement-in-clause-with-dapper-extensions-predicate).

Now, I want to implement `NOT IN` clause.
So, I am expecting SQL query something like below:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField NOT IN (param1, param2)
```

But I could not find anything about `NOT IN` or `NOT` clause in Dapper Extensions.

How can I implement `NOT IN` clause with Dapper Extensions Predicate?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49778821/5779732) (linked in question as well) to understand how to implement `IN` clause.

To turn the `IN` clause as mentioned above to `NOT IN` clause, use the last `bool not` parameter.
This is optional parameter and default value for it is `false`.
That is why; even though so obvious, it is bit *hidden* and hence *undiscovered*.
Documentation does not mention it explicitly either.

Below are the definitions of each predicate defined in Dapper Extensions source code:

```
public static class Predicates
{
    public static IBetweenPredicate Between<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, BetweenValues values, bool not = false) where T : class;
    public static IExistsPredicate Exists<TSub>(IPredicate predicate, bool not = false) where TSub : class;
    public static IFieldPredicate Field<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Operator op, object value, bool not = false) where T : class;
    public static IPropertyPredicate Property<T, T2>(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, Operator op, Expression<Func<T2, object>> expression2, bool not = false)
        where T : class
        where T2 : class;
}
```

Sample code is as below:

```
var predicate = Predicates.Field<Customer>
                (f => f.CustomerID, Operator.Eq, listOfIDs, true);
```

Observe the value `true` for last parameter in above code. The `listOfIDs` is an `IEnumerable` of your data type.

Please refer to [this](https://github.com/tmsmith/Dapper-Extensions/wiki/Predicates#multiple-compound-predicates-predicate-group) for more source code.