# How to write 'Not Equal' clause in Dapper Extension?

Tags: dapper, dapper-extensions

I want to create below SQL query in dapper extentions.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Description FROM tblPeople WHERE ID = 2 AND
 (AddressTown IS NOT NULL AND AddressTown<>'') ORDER BY Description ;
```

I have tried so far:

```
PredicateGroup pgMain = new PredicateGroup 
  { Operator = GroupOperator.And, Predicates = new List<IPredicate>() };
pgMain.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<tblPeople >(f => f.ID, Operator.Eq, 2));  
var peopleList = connection.GetList<tblPeople>(pgMain);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the last `bool not` parameter. This is optional parameter and default value for it is `false`.

So, your new code should be like as below:

```
pgMain.Predicates.Add(Predicates.Field<tblPeople>(f => f.ID, Operator.Eq, 2, true));
```

Observe the value `true` for last parameter in above code.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63831728/5779732) answer for more details.